# how to archive artifacts at the end of pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline

```
node ("testNode"){
   dev env = ${ENV};

   stage ("Copy artifact"){
   copyArtifacts(projectName: 'appBuildJob',selector: lastCompleted());
   }

   stage ("Archive artifact"){
   // Archive the build output artifacts.
   archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'app/build/outputs/apk/app-${ENV}.apk';
   }

  stage ('env1'){
        if (env == "env1") {
            buildResult = build(job: 'env1Tests',propagate: false).result;
           currentBuild.description = 'env1 - ' + buildResult 
        } else {
            echo 'Env param is ' + env +'. Nothing to do here.';
        }
  }
  stage ('env2'){
       if (env == "env2") {
            buildResult = build(job: 'env2Tests',propagate: false).result;
           currentBuild.description = 'env2 - ' + buildResult 
       } else {
           echo 'Env param is ' + env +'. Nothing to do here.';
       }           
   }
}
```

My problem is that the job appBuildJob can have either env1 or env2 param and both env1Tests and env2Tests depends on the artifact of my pipeline. So if for example now runs env1 it saves the artifact and everything. Then if I run env2 my env2Tests will fail because it can't find env2 app, it will find only env1 app. After this fails and the pipeline ends i have my env2 artifact saved. So if I run immediately emv2 it will work

I want to save and overwrite the artifact at the end of the "Archive artifact" stage but it only does that when all the pipeline ended.

Comment: It looks like you start by copying artifacts and then archiving them and only after that you run the other jobs?

Comment: @MaratC yes .... dev team build the app (they have a single job with env params) .. I copy their artifact and store it in jobs for each env and then run tests (i need to run test on all env on-demand on lastest build for each env)